# Antithetic sampling on non-linear payoff?

Tags: monte-carlo, pricing

If I wish to price an option with Monte Carlo using the standard GBM process, which have payoff

$(max(S-K,0))^2$

Why is it not suitable for a non-linear payoff?

Comment: Note:  the squared term is always positive, so the $max$ part is superfluous

Comment: @dm63 yes you are right, I meant the squared bracket outside the MAX function. Will edit. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: First this is a poorly worded question. How does one know what "it" is, without reading the title? Second, from what source do you allege "it" is not suitable?